# Reactjs - Moving a list item to another list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm slowly getting the knack (I think) for react. What I'm trying to do is display a list in one component and then make each list item (item 1, item 2, etc..) clickable so that when it is clicked, it can move back and forth between the two `<ItemList />` components. What I have is below, I think where my problem is setting the state on the first list in the `handleEvent()`.

```
class SingleItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let data = this.props.data;

    return (
        <li>
            <div> {data.name} </div>
        </li>
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends React.Component {
   render() {
     let itemArr = this.props.items;

     let listItems = itemArr.map((itemObj) => {
        return <SingleItem key={itemObj.id} data={itemObj}/>;
});

    return (
        <ul onClick={props.handleEvent}>
            {listItems}
        </ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        boxOne: {listItems},
        boxTwo:''
    };

    this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);
}

handleEvent() {
    this.setState({
        boxOne: this.state.boxTwo,
        boxTwo: this.state.boxOne
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ItemList items={this.state.boxOne} />
            <ItemList items={this.state.boxTwo} />
        </div>
    );
  }
};

var items = [
  {name: "Item 1", id: 1},
  {name: "Item 2", id: 2},
  {name: "Item 3", id: 3},
  {name: "Item 4", id: 4},
]

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I see you have `items` array at the bottom, what is `listItems` in the `App` component?

Comment: There are several problems with you code, it's also not very clear what you are trying to do. Please describe exactly what you expect and what failed.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is relatively straight forward, however yes, I agree with @webdeb, there are some problems with your code. Can you please set up a fiddle

Comment: For example this line cannot work `boxOne: {listItems},`

Comment: @FuriousD thank you for your responses, setting up a fiddle now

Comment: @FuriousD http://jsfiddle.net/vjeux/kb3gN/ here is a fiddle - although I could not get the fiddle to work..will keep looking into a way to get it going. However, this is pretty much what I am looking to do, have an element switching back and forth between two components. However, now, I am trying to do this with a JSON array (as you can see in my original post), and now I am trying to make them move when the actual list item is clicked on, and get rid of the button all together

Comment: @webdeb what I am trying to do is display a list of items from a JSON array and initially have them in one component `<ItemList />`. Ideally, each of these items would be clickable, so that when they are clicked ( each item individually), they will move to the other `<ItemList />`, which initially would be empty. Then with all the clicks from there on out, the individual list item would move back and forth with each click

Comment: There are many ways of doing it, but I would think about it not like moving ListItems, but calling events with some data, which indicates a change, and then based on those changes you just render the Items how you want, but your problem here is not React, but the design of the logic and data shapes.

Comment: @webdeb would it be best to split the two components up, such as `<ItemListOne />` and `<ItemListTwo/>`?

Comment: No need to split them, it's good to reuse them, check out my answer to understand the data shapes and logic, it's just an opinion but it should perform nicely ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it could be done..

So, I am passing the whole items array to all ItemLists, but I am also passing the state, which is just an array with ids of the included items in that list, check out the logic below and try to understand, it's easy actually..

```
class SingleItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let data = this.props.data;

    return (
        <li onClick={this.props.onClick}>
            <div> {data.name} </div>
        </li>
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends React.Component {
   render() {
     let itemArr = this.props.allItems;
     let myItems = this.props.items;
     let handleEvent = this.props.handleEvent;

     let listItems = itemArr.map((itemObj) => {
        if (!myItems.includes(itemObj.id)) return null;

        return <SingleItem 
          key={itemObj.id}
          data={itemObj}
          onClick={() => handleEvent(itemObj.id)}
        />;
     });

     return (
        <ul>
            {listItems}
        </ul>
     );
   }
}

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        boxOne: props.items.map(item => item.id), // init the boxes with itemIds
        boxTwo: []
    };

    this.handleEvent = this.handleEvent.bind(this);
}

handleEvent(itemId) {
    const isInBoxOne = this.state.boxOne.includes(itemId);

    // Heres the magic, if the item is in the first Box, filter it out,
    // and put into the second, otherwise the other way around..
    this.setState({
        boxOne: isInBoxOne
          ? this.state.boxOne.filter(i => i !== itemId)
          : [ ...this.state.boxOne, itemId ]
        boxTwo: isInBoxOne
          ? [ ...this.state.boxTwo, itemId ]
          : this.state.boxTwo.filter(i => i !== itemId)
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ItemList handleEvent={this.handleEvent} items={this.state.boxOne} allItems={this.props.items} />
            <ItemList handleEvent={this.handleEvent} items={this.state.boxTwo} allItems={this.props.items} />
        </div>
    );
  }
};

var items = [
  {name: "Item 1", id: 1},
  {name: "Item 2", id: 2},
  {name: "Item 3", id: 3},
  {name: "Item 4", id: 4},
]

ReactDOM.render(
  // Pass the initial items to your App
  <App items={items} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to go over this so I can get a better understanding for the logic and data shapes. However, I hate to bother you again..I cannot seem to get it to run as expected in my local dev enviornment. Do you know what my issue may be?

Comment: @BobbyTables yeah, I did't tested it.. I think you need to handle the onClick inside the 
`<li onClick={this.props.onClick}>{data.name}</li>`

Comment: if it's still not working, please check out the console and/or describe the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! much appreciated!

Comment: im not seeing any issues/errors in the console, however when executing, one list is displayed and the items are not clickable

Comment: try it with a button inside the `<li>` maybe pass the the onClick there.. try it with an anonymous function, do some console log, you'll get it ;)

Comment: yup, working like a charm now! Thanks for everything, again!